# How to assert the activity is finished with espresso

Tags: testing, android-espresso, androidx-test

I want to assert the activity is finished after clicking a button.
eg: if the user clicked button with id R.id.finish, then the activity is finished.

I'm trying to look up apis with ActivitySenerio and Espresso, but none of these helps.

Ref:

- https://developer.android.google.cn/training/testing/espresso

Answer (score 0):

Without ActivitySenerio:

```java
try {
    onView(withId(R.id.finish)).perform(click());
} catch (Exception e) {
    // assert the activity is finished
    assertEquals(NoActivityResumedException.class, e.getClass());
}
```

With ActivitySenerio(Rule):

```java
    activity.findViewById(R.id.finish).performclick();
    assertTrue(activity.isFinishing());
```